# #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded issue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this template and it's working fine

```
<h2>Listing videos</h2>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<%= for video <- @videos do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= video.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= video.url %></td>
      <td><%= video.title %></td>
      <td><%= video.description %></td>
      <td><%= if category = video.category, do: category.name %></td>

      <td class="text-right">
        <%= link "Show", to: video_path(@conn, :show, video), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Edit", to: video_path(@conn, :edit, video), class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
        <%= link "Delete", to: video_path(@conn, :delete, video), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link "New video", to: video_path(@conn, :new) %>
```

And when I wrote this test it started to complain about categories not being preloaded:

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoViewTest do
  use Rumbl.ConnCase, async: true
  import Phoenix.View

  test "renders index.html", %{conn: conn} do
    videos = [%Rumbl.Video{id: "1", title: "dogs"},
              %Rumbl.Video{id: "2", title: "cats"}]
    content = render_to_string(Rumbl.VideoView, "index.html",
                               conn: conn, videos: videos)

    assert String.contains?(content, "Listing videos")
    for video <- videos do
      assert String.contains?(content, video.title)
    end
  end

  test "renders new.html", %{conn: conn} do
    changeset = Rumbl.Video.changeset(%Rumbl.Video{})
    categories = [{"cats", 123}]
    content = render_to_string(Rumbl.VideoView, "new.html",
      conn: conn, changeset: changeset, categories: categories)
    assert String.contains?(content, "New video")
  end
end
```

Error:

```
...

  1) test renders index.html (Rumbl.VideoViewTest)
     test/views/video_view_test.exs:5
     ** (KeyError) key :name not found in: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :category is not loaded>
     code: content = render_to_string(Rumbl.VideoView, "index.html",
     stacktrace:
       (rumbl) web/templates/video/index.html.eex:21: anonymous fn/3 in Rumbl.VideoView."index.html"/1
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1811: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (rumbl) web/templates/video/index.html.eex:15: Rumbl.VideoView."index.html"/1
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:335: Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:342: Phoenix.View.render_to_string/3
       test/views/video_view_test.exs:8: (test)
```

Why it complains? where do I have to preload the categories? I dont understand that error, if video doesnt have any category it shouldnt crash

Updated with controller index view code

```
  def index(conn, _params, user) do
    videos = Repo.all(user_videos(user)) |> Repo.preload(:category)
    render(conn, "index.html", videos: videos)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must preload category in controller.

You don't know if video has any category before preloading it (not by asking `if video.category`). This is because `video.category` without preloading returns `#Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :category is not loaded>`, not `nil` you have expected.

For single category you can ask `if video.category_id`, assuming that video `belongs_to` category. It will give you `nil` if video has no category.

Comment: mm then something like this could work? <td><%= if video.category_id && category = video.category, do: category.name %></td> although Im having syntax problems

Comment: It could, but it won't if video has category and it is not preloaded.

Comment: mm I noticed I am already preloading the categories in the controller videos = Repo.all(user_videos(user)) |> Repo.preload(:category) so I shouldnt get the error right?

Comment: Preload them in user_videos query.

Comment: mm how can I do that? this is my user_videos defp   defp user_videos(user) do
    # query user videos
    assoc(user, :videos)
  end

Comment: Just calling Repo.preload(:category) after assoc?

Comment: I was talking about usual way of making query, like `from(v in Video, ...., preload: [:category]`.

Comment: Sorry I am really new to elixir/phoenix and dont understand what you mean, do you mean to rewrite user_videos method?

Comment: Looks like it needs rewrite. Look here, first example: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html

Comment: I am trying this but this receiving the same "not preloaded error"
 defp user_videos(user) do
    query = (from u in user, select: u.videos, preload: [:category])
    Repo.all(query)
end
user model has many has_many :videos, Rumbl.Video

Comment: `preload: [videos: :category]`